# Better way to find site lists when using a farm level job?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

There's a job on the farm level that uses lists out of a site collection. So before calling the lists the job has to find the site where those lists reside. Now I tried two ways to work it around:

1) An empty site-level featue. In the execute method of the farm job I look for the first encounted site in which that feature is activated. It works perfectly. The drawback is an excta feature and some extrea time for sacnning through all the sites and their features.

2) In the feature event of the site solution I write the site url into the  farm's property bag. Then in the job's Execute I read the Url from the farm property bag. But it requires additional proveledges and makes you install a site level solution under the SP_Farm account or something like that.

So are there any other ways to configure for farm level job peoprely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could the job run on webapplication-level instead? That way it would automatically only access the sites on that webapp..

Comment: Yes, webApplication is sent as a parameter in the SPJobDefinition constructor. And still I need to walk through the all feaures of all the sites that belong to that webapp. So the problem still takes place.

Answer (score 0):

How are the lists created? What list definition do the lists use? If the lists are created manually without a particular list definition, that would introduce risk regarding the reliability of the job's execution. If the lists are created automatically or are using a certain custom list definition, then why not use that to identify the lists?

I bring all of this up because I have used something close to your first option. But far from being an empty feature, my feature contains the custom list definition and/or the list instances of the lists that my job will use.

Comment: The lists can be created from their templates at any momnet by the end user. Now I avoieded using an extra empty feature. In my site-scoped project I use a feature event receicver in which on activation I create a certain property and store it in the site family's prop bag. Then, when job's executing, it runs through all the top sites and checks if it contains the prop I created. I think is less slow and does not require any extra priveledges.